# Calculating Christoffel symbols from variational principles

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, variational-principle, geodesics

How to find Christoffel symbol by variational principles?

For example:

Consider the 2d metric

ds^2 = -e^2ky dt^2 + dy^2

Derive the Christoffel symbols for this metric using variational principle.

Comment: Finding this question saved me from asking something that would have elicited the answer Qmechanic gave. Which was exactly what I was looking for. So I give them both an up vote.

Answer (score 1):

Given a pseudo-Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, the main idea is that by varying the action  $$S[x] ~:=~\int\! \mathrm{d}\tau~g_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^{\mu}\dot{x}^{\nu},\tag{1} $$ whose [EL equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) are the [geodesic equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity) $$\ddot{x}^{\lambda}+\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu}~\dot{x}^{\mu}\dot{x}^{\nu}~=~0,\tag{2}$$ then the Christoffel symbols can be read of as coefficient functions among the dotted variables in eqs. (2). This method is sometimes useful, partly because the calculation tends to carry fewer external indices (as compared to just apply the definition directly), and especially when many Christoffel symbols are zero by symmetry.